# PHP create an excel file and return it via a function

Tags: php, yii2, attachment, yii2-advanced-app, phpspreadsheet

I am working on `yii2`. I am creating an excel file via `php spreadsheet`. For now, I am downloading it in a browser. Now, I want to return the file without downloading it.

**Code**:

```
// Created 2 worksheet in one excel file successfully 

$filename = 'Meter Breakdown List '.date('d-m-y').'.xlsx'; //save our workbook as this file name
    // Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Xlsx)
    header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'"');
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
    // If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
    header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

    $writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');

    $writer->save('php://output');
```

After that I want it to return the file like `return $filename;`

The returned file is then passed to a function named `sendEmail($filename)`

In this function, I have already setup email sending process via attachment.

How can I send the file without downloading it?

**Note:**

I have also looked at the question: [PHP create Excel spreadsheet and then email it as an attachment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4993300/php-create-excel-spreadsheet-and-then-email-it-as-an-attachment).

Comment: Also remove your header functions

Comment: @ManiMuthuPandi all headers?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson the path would be absolute?

Comment: @MagnusEriksson put this as an answer, as actually it is a concrete answer

Comment: Content-Disposition is the main one for downloading  the file

Comment: you dont actually need to save the file if all your going to do is send it. phpmailer will take a stream as attachment, more efficient than file creation if you are not wanting to keep it

Comment: Ok, I have commented all of the headers and save. The only part which is not commented is `$writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');`

When I try to send the email I am getting `Swift_IoException` the error is `Unable to open file for reading [Meter Breakdown List 28-05-18.xlsx]`

Comment: @MagnusEriksson I have tried your way by commenting the header section and then by doing `$writer = \PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');

        $writer->save('/inventory-web/Files/'.$filename);

        return Url::toRoute('/inventory-web/Files/'.$filename);`

But I am getting error `Could not open /inventory-web/Files/Meter Breakdown List 28-05-18.xlsx for writing.`

Comment: @ManiMuthuPandi I have tried each and every possible way but still, I am unable to return the file. Can you please help me out on this?

Comment: Do you require the file to be stored on the server? Or is it a one-time deal? If you don't need to save it, it wouldn't make much sense to store it in a file, but `php://memory` might be better suited. You'd then might have to refactor your `sendEmail` to take in a filehandle instead of a filename.

Comment: @k0pernikus no I don't want to save it on the server

Comment: @MrFaisal It appears that `PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet` only allows writing to a file, and if you try to replace `'php://output'` with `'php://memory` you'll lose the filehandle in the process. Due to that restriction of `PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet` I recommend creating a temporay file through [tempnam](http://php.net/manual/de/function.tempnam.php).

Comment: Interestingly enough, internally phpspreadshee is using tempnam when using `php://output` or `php://stdout`. See the implementation of the [xlx-writer](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PhpSpreadsheet/blob/dcc18322155aed681bc7b1c15d9fb055ee7c8afb/src/PhpSpreadsheet/Writer/Xlsx.php#L179)

Comment: looks like its been solved already

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sample [code](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/develop/) to save the file

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet;
use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Writer\Xlsx;

$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello World !');

$writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
$writer->save('hello world.xlsx');
```

Once file saved, you can send the file to mail

```
sendEmail('hello world.xlsx');
```

Once done everything you may delete the saved file

```
unlink('hello world.xlsx');
```