# decoding pdf string and sending it by codeigniter email functionality

Tags: php, codeigniter, email, pdf, dompdf

I am using dompdf to generate a pdf and I am taking the raw string, encoding it for saving it to the database later and then decoding it so I can send it as a attachment for the email, but I cannot do it anyhow. I tried both the examples here [PHP Send email with PDF attachment without creating the file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2146591/php-send-email-with-pdf-attachment-without-creating-the-file) and [PHP get pdf file from base64 encoded data string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17022101/php-get-pdf-file-from-base64-encoded-data-string) but I could not get it working.

So here is the code

```
public function generateCreditAggreement(){
        $this->load->helper('file'); 
        require_once(APPPATH.'third_party/dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php');

            $dompdf = new Dompdf();


            $msg = $this->load->view('credit_agreement_view', '', true);
            $html = mb_convert_encoding($msg, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');
            $dompdf->load_html($html);

//            $dompdf->set_paper('A4', 'Potrait');
            $paper_orientation = 'Potrait';

            $dompdf->set_paper($paper_orientation);

            // Render the HTML as PDF
            $dompdf->render();

            // Output the generated PDF to Browser
//          $dompdf->stream('document.pdf');
//          $id = "sup";
//          $dompdf->stream("$id.pdf", array("Attachment" => false));           

            $pdf_string =   $dompdf->output();

            $new_pdf = write_file('name', $pdf_string);


            $pdf_content =  base64_encode($pdf_string);
//          $this->load->model('agreement_page');
//          $pushString = $this->agreement_page->storePdfString($pdf_content);

            //Decode pdf content
            $pdf_decoded = base64_decode ($pdf_content);
            //Write data back to pdf file
            $pdf = fopen ('credit_agreement.pdf','w');
            fwrite ($pdf,$pdf_decoded);
            //close output file
            fclose ($pdf);




            // sending the pdf to email



            $this->load->library('email');
            $config['protocol'] = 'smtp';

            $config['smtp_host'] = 'ssl://smtp.gmail.com';

            $config['smtp_port']    = '465';

            $config['smtp_timeout'] = '7';

            $config['smtp_user']    = 'support@aurorax.co';

            $config['smtp_pass']    = '';

            $config['charset']    = 'utf-8';

            $config['newline']    = "\r\n";

            $config['mailtype'] = 'text'; // or html

            $config['validation'] = TRUE; // bool whether to validate email or not      

            $this->email->initialize($config);

            $this->email->from('support@aurorax.co', 'aurora exchange');
            $this->email->to('masnad@aurorax.co');
            $this->email->subject('pdf');
            $this->email->attach('myfile.pdf' , $pdf,'application/pdf');
            $this->email->message('Your pdf is here');  
//            $this->email->attach($pdf);
            $this->email->send();      

    }
```

Struggling for a 2 days now, cant get it working.

Comment: whats output or error??

Comment: Sends a email without any pdf file attached and $pdf says  (resource) resource id='172' type='Unknown'

Comment: $pdf has null value means ??

Comment: Sorry it didnt say null it says (resource) resource id='172' type='Unknown'

Comment: is your pdf get written correctly ??

Comment: yup if I just change  $dompdf->output(); to $dompdf->stream("$id.pdf", array("Attachment" => false));     I get to see the pdf which is written correctly , but I am taking the string and using that instead of generated pdf

Comment: i'm unclear with your purpose

Comment: what I want to do is get the pdf string, and encode it first to store it in the database, and if later I would want to send the pdf as a email I would get the string from the database and decode it and send it as a attachment in the email, like different users might want to get their pdf files multiples times as email.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114924/discussion-between-abdulla-and-masnad-nihit).

Comment: @Abdulla I guess I failed terribly so could you help me out in this by storing it in a specific file and then using that file to store it as a attachment in the email??? Should have listened to you back then :(

Answer (score 1):

I changed two lines of  Codeigniter Email class, so that I can send base64 string as attachments easily.

https://github.com/aqueeel/CI-Base64EmailAttach

Download and replace your email class with this.

Initialize config array as:

```
$config['_encoding'] = 'base64';
$this->load->library('email',$config);
```

Call the attachmnet function with mime type:

```
$this->email- >attach($base64,'attachment','report.pdf','application/pdf');.
```

Comment: Tell me if i'm using a wrong way. I cant find any other options.